# SQLAlchemy: .label() an addition of values

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I know it's possible to label an arbitrary column in a query:

```
session.query(Person.name.label("name"))
```

It isn't possible to do this:

```
session.query((Person.age + Person.wealth).label("sum"))
```

How would I go about labeling an addition of different columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Seems like it can be solved with literal_column which takes arbitrary column names as text and returns SQLAlchemy objects.
    session.query(literal_column("age + wealth").label("lbl"))*

Edit:
Using

```
session.query((Person.age + Person.wealth).label("lbl"))
```

works. My bad

Comment: What's the difference against the OP's `session.query((Person.age + Person.wealth).label("sum"))
`?